# MYSQL Table alias best practice

Tags: mysql

I have two questions about table aliases...

Firstly, is

```
SELECT * FROM myTable AS x
```

the same as

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE x
```

and if so which is best practice?

Comment: the second one is faster to type! :)

Comment: @TinTran SELECT * is also faster to type. Typing speed <> best practice.

Comment: Yes, they are the same, and no, neither is best practice.  `SELECT *` is shorthand for "I'm lazy in the worst possible of ways."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think either are very good.  If you are going to give a table an alias, have the alias mean something with respect to the table.  Initials are a good way to start:

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM myTable mt
```

My personal *preference* is to use `as` for column aliases and to omit it for table aliases.  This is because without the `as` for columns, these look almost the same, leading to error-prone queries:

```
select a, b
select a b
```

As for `as` in the `from` clause.  MS Access requires it.  Oracle doesn't recognize it.  In general, for most databases it is optional, and I omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are same. They will give the same results.

Comment: `select count(*) lcount from table1;` is also valid... not sure what your point is.

Comment: Sorry my bad, its also acceptable ... thx , never tried it that way